# Vectorised approach to parsing column of URLs in R

Tags: r

I've got a 2 column data frame that consists of user_id and the url that they entered the site on. I'm keen to parse some key data out of the URL.

The `parse_url` function from the `httr` pacakge seems to do a nice job of extracting the key fields but I'm stuck as to how turn this into an efficient process that creates a new data frame - I know that the 'easy option' of writing a 'for loop' is not the way to go.

I've tried a basic approach with `sapply` which *seems* to be a step in the right direction but the transformation it does in its basic form isn't what I'm looking for.

One potential complication is that the function nests the elements of the url separated by `&` as a list within a top level variable called `Query`. My simple manual example looks like this:

```
library(httr)
x <- parse_url("http://www.thesite.com/en/landingpage1?currency=GBP&utm_term=bar&creative=15895258")
c(x$query$utm_term, x$query$creative)
[1] "bar"    "15895258"
```

My original data frame looks like this:

```
user_id | url
=======================================
50      | http://www.thesite.com/en/lpage1?currency=GBP&utm_term=bar&creative=15895258

51      | http://www.thebsite.com/en/lpage2?currency=GBP&utm_term=foo&creative=15895852

52      | http://www.thesite.com/en/lpage1?currency=USD&utm_term=foobar&creative=15895498
```

And the desired output looks like this:

```
user_id | utm_term  | creative
-----------------------------------
50      | bar       | 15895258
51      | foo       | 15895852
52      | foobar    | 15895498
```

Any help or ideas appreciated!
Jacob

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with `for`, on condition that you pre-allocate memory and don't assign in place.  If you are comfortable with the `for` idiom, take a look at `foreach` which combines the benefits of `lapply` with the idiom of `for`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `regex`

```
  library(stringi)
  df[,2:3] <- setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
          stri_extract_all_regex(df$url, "(?<=utm_term=|creative=)[A-Za-z0-9]+")),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE), c("utm_term", "creative"))
  df
   # user_id    url creative
  #1      50    bar 15895258
  #2      51    foo 15895852
  #3       2 foobar 15895498
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 setDT(df)[, c('url', 'creative') := tstrsplit(url, '^.*term=|&creative=',
              type.convert=TRUE)[-1]][]
 #   user_id    url creative
 #1:      50    bar 15895258
 #2:      51    foo 15895852
 #3:       2 foobar 15895498
```

#### data

```
  df <- structure(list(user_id = c(50L, 51L, 2L), url = c("http://www.thesite.com/en/lpage1?currency=GBP&utm_term=bar&creative=15895258", 
 "http://www.thebsite.com/en/lpage2?currency=GBP&utm_term=foo&creative=15895852", 
 "http://www.thesite.com/en/lpage1?currency=USD&utm_term=foobar&creative=15895498"
 )), .Names = c("user_id", "url"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```

Comment: Hey, love the idea of doing this with regex and really keen to get it running this way although get the following error:Warning messages:
1: In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
2: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 2:3, value = list(utm_term = c("27601389703",  :
  provided 3 variables to replace 2 variables

Comment: @Jacob  Could you show your example data using `dput`  For example `dput(head(df, 10))`  In the data I provided, it didn't show any errors.

Answer (score 0):

If your `data.frame` is `df`:

```
res <- sapply(df$url, function(u) {
    x <- parse_url(u)
    c(x$query$utm_term, x$query$creative)
})
res <- data.frame(user_id=df$user_id,
                  utm_term=res[1,],
                  creative=res[2,])
res
##   user_id utm_term creative
## 1      50      bar 15895258
## 2      51      foo 15895852
## 3      52   foobar 15895498
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks - seems to produce a list, what I'm really after is a 2 column df.

Comment: Strange. For me `res` is a `data.frame` with the format you specify as desired in the question

Answer (score 0):

Using apply, and running function over each row

```
df=data.frame(id=50:52,url=c("http://www.thesite.com/en/lpage1?currency=GBP&utm_term=bar&creative=15895258",
                             "http://www.thebsite.com/en/lpage2?currency=GBP&utm_term=foo&creative=15895852",
                             "http://www.thesite.com/en/lpage1?currency=USD&utm_term=foobar&creative=15895498"))

df2=as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,apply(df,1,function(x){      #row binding everything
  c(x["id"],parse_url(x["url"])$query[c("utm_term","creative")]) #adding id,utm_term and creative
  })))
```

Comment: Thanks! On the real data is get NA for the user_id column (including the header). Any ideas?